# How do you read/write/update m4u and mp3 file meta data using cocoa/objective c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mp3, metadata, m4a

Are there some particular library files available on OS/X that are relevant, I am just not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to use the QuickTime for that. There is some [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/QTMetaData/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003766-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) that does this. However, it's not the nicest way to access metadata. The newer QTKit Framework somehow still requires you to fall back to the C-based APIs. There is [another example](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2007/qa1515.html) from Apple embedding meta data writing into a Objective-C method. This might be the best starting point for you.